# Adding functions into class but avoid recompilation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Currently I have a

`Class ModelFac: public Singleton <ModelFac>{
    public:
      friend class Singleton <ModelFac>;
      ModelFacPtr CreateModelA (bool buy, std::string ccy, const std::string& str){
        //some implementations here
     }
      ModelFacPtr CreateModelB (bool buy, std::string useful_ccy){
        //other implementations
     }
};`

When I want to call functions, I will call `ModelFac::Instance().CreateModelA(a,b,c)`. Those functions are being called in different `.cc` files. However when I add new `CreateModelC` function, all files that calls `ModelFac::Instance().CreateModelX(a,b,c,d,e)` will need to be recompiled since they all include `ModelFac.h`, which is really time consuming.

Can I somehow fix this situaion but still leave `ModelFac::Instance().CreateModelA(a,b,c)` this type of call format for implementation?

I don't want to make different classes for different `CreateModel` functions, which will cause a lot fixes in the whole program. It will be greate if I can still use `ModelFac::Instance()` but then pass `CreateModelA` as the first argument.

Thanks.

Comment: If you actually "have" that, what you have is not C++. Please post real code using copy and paste.

Comment: if `CreateModelC` is a public function there isn't much you can do, if its private then you can use the pimpl idiom to hide the function from the header file

Comment: Try passing pointers to functions or function objects.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The code belongs to a big project that it's really hard to post all the implementation. What do you mean by actually "have" that? Do you mean the fix solution won't exist?

Comment: not sure what Neil is refering to but just as an example `Class` is not a keyword in c++, neither can you write `a list of arguments` in a signature without the compiler throwing errors on you. This may seem like minor nitpick, but when discussing code it helps to look at code instead of something that almost looks like code

Comment: I have edited my post again. Is this time a bit helpful?

Comment: If you change something in `ModelFac.h` then all units #including this file need to be recompiled.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm trying to find a solution that can let me keep what is in ModelFac.h the same as origin, but still adds new functions. It's ok if we change the structure of class ModelFac or so on, but I really want the format when we call the functions doesn't change too much.

Comment: If I make it private, can I somehow still get the returned value by CreateModelC outside of the class? @AlanBirtles

Comment: No, by moving it into a pimpl class it wouldn't even be visible in the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new *general* method `CreateModel` to your `ModelFac` class (I'm assuming the type `ModelFacPtr` should be `ModelPtr` for better naming, but this is not important to my solution):

```
class ModelFac : public Singleton<ModelFac> {
public:
    ...
    ModelPtr CreateModelA(bool buy, std::string ccy, const std::string& str) {...}
    ModelPtr CreateModelB(bool buy, std::string useful_ccy) {...}

    ModelPtr CreateModel(Creator& creator) { return creator.Create(); }
};
```

Here is the `Creator` interface (of course you need to declare it before the `ModelFac` class):

```
class Creator {
public:
    virtual ModelPtr Create() = 0;
};
```

Each time you have a new type of model to create, let's say model `C`, just write a new `Creator` class:

```
class CCreator : public Creator {
public:
    CCreator(bool buy, std::string foo, int bar)
        : m_buy(buy), m_foo(foo), m_bar(bar) {}
    ModelPtr Create() {
        // use m_buy, m_foo, and m_bar to create and return the model
    }
private:
    bool m_buy;
    std::string m_foo;
    int m_bar;
};
```

Now, to create a model `C`, write:

```
ModelFac::Instance().CreateModel( CCreator(true, "haha", 777) );
```

As you can see, the `ModelFac` class is not modified each time you have a new type of `Model`. What you need is to write a new `Creator` class.

Comment: Thanks! Can we also add a map to `ModelFac` and register the new model we created in `CCreator.cc` into the map so that I don't even need to include `CCreator.h` into the file that calls `ModelFac::Instance().CreateModel( CCreator(true, "haha", 777) )`?